# Why is C closer to the hardware?

Tags: c

One of the advantages of C is that it is closer to the hardware. 
But I do not understand what does it really mean. It would be great help if someone could elaborate.

Comment: Do you mean in comparison to java?

Comment: Even that answer will do, if it helps me understand:)

Comment: It has to be closer to the hardware _than something else_. C is not closer to the hardware compared to assembler, on the contrary it is far from the hardware. So your question doesn't make any sense. Even if it did, it is far too broad for Stack Overflow. One could easily write a book about all the things in C that makes it closer to the hardware than for example Java.

Answer (score 6):

There's no virtual machine interpreting C executable code.  It's compiled into machine instructions, specific to a particular CPU, that are linked together and run on your hardware.

Another reason is the design of the language itself.  When Kernighan and Ritchie were developing C for DEC hardware, they were very mindful of actual hardware features like registers, bit shifting, etc.  There wasn't a layer of abstraction between their thinking and the machine for which they were writing the language.

Comment: The operators in C are usually close to a 1-1 mapping with the respective assembly instructions in many architectures too. For example a single pointer dereference (or array indexing in general for that matter) often translates to a single instruction.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare `C` with `java`, C is closer to the hardware, because java does not directly operate on the system. Java is executed on the [java virtual machine](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine), which then operates on the system.

C does not have such a layer between it and the system and is therefore closer to the harware.

Comment: You can compile Java to native code, if you want, with e.g. `gcj`. The implementation of a language compiler has nothing to do with the properties of a language itself.

Answer (score 0):

It does not provide abstractions to protect you from the specifics of the hardware and platform, such as memory layout and system APIs. Thus is it "closer to the hardware" in the sense that there is less code between your code and the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

A [definitive answer](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html):

> BCPL, B, and C all fit firmly in the traditional procedural family typified by Fortran and Algol 60...**They are `close to the machine' in that the abstractions they introduce are readily grounded in the concrete data types and operations supplied by conventional computers**, and they rely on library routines for input-output and other interactions with an operating system. With less success, they also use library procedures to specify interesting control constructs such as coroutines and procedure closures. At the same time, their abstractions lie at a sufficiently high level that, with care, portability between machines can be achieved.

For a specific example, a C `int` will most likely map to an object of the native word size (16-, 32-, 64-, or 128-bit), and operations on that `int` object will be performed using native opcodes (ADD, MUL, etc.).

Contrast that with languages like Lisp or Haskell that use *arbitrary-precision* arithmetic; integers in those languages are often represented by arrays of digits, and operations on them are performed almost exclusively in software.

In this respect, C is "close to the hardware" in that it's taking advantage of the native infrastructure for integer operations.

All things being equal, integer arithmetic in C will be a *lot* faster since it's taking advantage of the native hardware, but it cannot represent or operate on arbitrarily large values.